# Why does fgets() accept (signed) int for its 'count' argument?

Tags: arrays, c, language-lawyer, fgets

The standard function `fgets` is specified this way in the upcoming C23 Standard:

> **7.23.7.2 The fgets function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <stdio.h>
>     char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by `stream` into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `fgets` function returns `s` if successful. If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned. If a read error occurs during the operation, the members of the array have unspecified values and a null pointer is returned.

This specification is unchanged since the original ANSI-C document, except for the `restrict` keywords added in C99.

The type specified for `n` is `int`, which is inconsistent with all other C library functions taking an array length or an object count where the type is `size_t`. This problem cannot be fixed without potentially breaking programs that use function pointers pointing to `fgets` or that pass negative values for `n`.  `fread` and `fwrite`, along with many other standard functions used to have their numeric arguments and return values specified as `int` in the original Unix documents, but were changed before ANSI-C, which begs the question: *Why was `fgets` left out of this update, was there any compelling reason to treat `fgets()` differently then?*

Furthermore, some cases do not seem to have specified behavior:

- if `n <= 1`, should `fgets()` return `s` without trying to read from the stream?
- if `n == 1`, should `s[0]` be set to a null character albeit no characters have been read into the array?
- if `n <= 0`, can we pass a null pointer for `s`?

Comment: "*which is inconsistent as it should be size_t*" - inconsistent with what exactly, since it has always been `int`? You mean with other functions from `stdio.h`? Yeah, that is true, but as you say you can't realy change that without breaking everything. That seems like a pretty compelling reason to me :'). As per `fread` and `fwrite`, those have had `size_t` since C89, so nothing was changed.

Comment: The whole of `stdio.h` is one big design flaw - we've known this since forever. It's basically like the Leaning Tower of Pisa, it has gone to a point where the flaws are so eye-catching and well-known that they have become the defining features. For `fgets` specifically, the main flaw is that there's no version of it which doesn't spew new lines into the buffer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `size_t` was introduced some time before C89 and all other C library functions use `size_t` to specify array lengths or object counts. `fread` and `fwrite`, along with many other functions used to have their numeric arguments and return values specified as `int` in the original Unix documents, but were changed before ANSI-C, which begs the question: why was `fgets` left out of this update, was there any *compelling reason* to treat `fgets()` differently then?

Comment: It is as it is. Simply avoid those cases where `n <= 1`.

Comment: @Lundin Leaving the newline in lets you discriminate between reading a full line or a partial one. Not really a flaw.

Comment: Passing a null pointer for `s` is always UB by 7.1.4p1.

Comment: @Shawn Designing an input function API is not rocket science. What all sensible APIs do is something like `status_t input (uint8_t* buf, size_t buf_size, size_t* bytes_read);` That covers a vast number of use cases. Functions that make an unholy mess combining data and function result status in one aren't well-designed.

Comment: @Lundin Including the number of bytes read has no bearing on my point about telling if a full or partial line was read (though it is often useful). Would you have whatever a `status_t` is include information like that? Personally I prefer POSIX `getline()`, which grows its input buffer if needed to always read a complete line (and still leaves the newline, in this case so you can tell when the last line of input doesn't end in one in case that's important). *Functions that make an unholy mess combining data and function result status* `fgets()` doesn't really do that?

Comment: @Shawn You could create return codes to suit your needs such as `OK_EOF`, `OK_LF`, `ERR_TIMEOUT` or whatever makes sense. Then if you care if the input is ended with line feed or not, you could check the results. Or if you don't care maybe invent something like `OK = OK_EOF | OK_LF` (assuming these are enums or `#defines` or whatever).

Comment: @Shawn As for `getline`, it is infamous as the function which has caused most memory leaks throughout the history of programming, all languages, all categories... This because it combines low level stuff like dynamic allocation with high level stuff like reading from stdin. It's a horribly designed function so it's a wonder that it wasn't included in stdio.h with the rest. Although POSIX too is a collection of the worst designed functions in history...

Comment: @Shawn "Functions that make an unholy mess combining data and function result status fgets() doesn't really do that?"  It returns a null pointer upon error instead of having a dedicated result type. And that's how you get null pointers into your data. It's also a well-known flaw of  `fgets` that it doesn't return the number of bytes read. And well, every single function in the standard C library which returns a pointer to the first parameter is pretty much by definition flawed for that reason alone. Well-designed functions only have one entry and one exit for one particular data.

Comment: @Lundin 99% of the time `fgets()` is used its return value is just treated as a boolean; sure it's odd that it returns a pointer instead of an int, but it doesn't really make a difference in practice. And definitely doesn't matter wrt leaving a newline in the string unless you're proposing it returns more than a simple boolean value.

Comment: `getline()` only leaks memory if you use it wrong, just like any function that allocates memory. I'd give `realloc()` the crown for "most leaks" myself, if you want to see an actually poorly designed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the behavior for `n <= 1`:

There is no formal definition of *successful* in the context of this specification, and the only cases of failure that come to mind relate to reading from the stream and getting an error or reaching the end of file, both cases addressed in the specification.

Since `fgets()` *reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`*, it should not read any characters for `n <= 1`, hence not attempt any input from the stream.  Therefore, the `fgets()` should return `s` in this case.

It seems unspecified if `s` must be modified and `s[0]` set to a null character if `n == 1`, albeit all C libraries for which I have access to the source code do behave this way.

Because of this potential problem, It seems recommended to avoid calling `fgets()` with a value below `2` for argument `n`.

Note that `snprintf` has a similar problem:

> **7.23.6.5 The `snprintf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <stdio.h>
>     int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream. If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is both nonnegative and less than `n`.

The sentence *and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array* is somewhat ambiguous if no characters have actually been written to the array, either because the output is empty or because it has been completely discarded.

Despite this ambiguity, it seems impossible to argue that `snprintf` given an empty format string may not produce an empty string in `s` provided `n` is non zero.

It would be helpful to use a more precise specification of both `snprintf` and `fgets` regarding the case of `n == 1`, ensuring that `s[0]` be set to a null character.

Comment: I think `n==1` and `n<=0` are different cases. At least Glibc treats the two cases differently.

Comment: The `sprintf` function has similar language: "*A null character is written at the end of the characters written*". You could argue that is "somewhat ambiguous" if no characters are actually written. Personally, I do not interpret it as being ambiguous. I interpret as meaning a possibly empty sequence of characters is written and the null character is written after those.